# Worklight Adapter basic authentication

Tags: worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

Implemented Basic auth  based on the blog 
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/04/protect-adapter-backend/

the problem is its always giving invalid request as response when i provide basic auth headers, even though the credentials are correct,
if i dont provide basic auth header its giving  401 unauthorized

Comment: Are you using the attached sample or did you create your sample from scratch?

Comment: I did both ,  both my sample and attached sample are giving the same error

Comment: How are you testing? And which version of Worklight are you using?

Comment: version 7.0  , by invoking  adapter am testing , even i tested using Rest client

Comment: What do you mean by invoking adapter? In code or in eclipse? It won't work in eclipse. The best way to test is with Postman.

Comment: yes i tried both in eclipse and , using rest client Postman

Comment: if you remove the security test from the adapter, are you able, in Postman, to get the data from the adapter?

Comment: yes if i remove the security test it is working perfectly

Comment: From POSTMAN as well?

Comment: yes from postman and eclipse

Comment: I will try the sample myself. Please remove eclipse from all of your testing scenarios, it does not support security.

Comment: Ok thank you Nathan , Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps I took to reproduce:

1. Download sample as zip from https://github.com/nasht00/BackendAccessAuthentication
2. Import into MobileFirst Platform 7.0 Studio
3. Deploy adapter
4. In Postman, made a GET request to `http://localhost:10080/BackendAccessAuthentication/invoke?adapter=Protected&procedure=doAction&parameters=['hello']`
5. In the `Authorization` tab, I chose `Basic Auth` and entered `user` and `password`
6. Success

Are you doing anything different?

Comment: No same, i did the same thing, i removed the @Override from java file because it is giving error for me

Comment: http://localhost:10080/BackendAccessAuthentication/invoke?adapter=Protected&procedure=doAction&parameters=['hello']   This will always give Success even there is no Basic auth header,  But i tried using the following way    http://localhost:10080/BackendAccessAuthentication/adapters/Protected/doAction?params=["hello"]

Comment: it is working with  /invoke?adapter=Protected&procedure=doAction&parameters=['hello'] but not with    /adapters/Protected/doAction?params=["hello"]

Comment: I am confused, so you are NOT doing the exact same thing right? If you use the exact same URL as me, it works?

Comment: As u suggested i changed the URl Schema it works for me its appending " /* secure"  before the json  '*/ ' after the json response